# Find data based on data fields haskell

Tags: haskell

I have an algebraic data type called `Person` looks like this:

```
data Person = 
   Person { firstName :: String
          , lastName  :: String
          , height    :: Float
          , age       :: Int
          } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I also have a list of `Person` filled with various information about people, now say I want to return all the data of one specific `Person` based on `firstName` alone, how would I do that?

Like search through all the `firstName`s stored in the list, and then returning either `Just Person` if the query matches or `Nothing` if there isn't any match

Answer (score 4):

You can use `filter` to return a list that contains all the `Person` with a given condition on `firstName`.

For instance:

```
filter (\x -> firstName x == "John") xs
```

where `xs` contains the list of `Person`. This will return an empty list (`[]`) if no `Person` matches the criteria.

Comment: If you're only interested in the first match, you can use `Data.Maybe.listToMaybe` on the filtered list.

Comment: ... or you can use `Data.List.find`.

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, you could write a custom lookup function:

```
lookupBy :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> b -> Maybe a
lookupBy _ [] _ = Nothing
lookupBy f (x:xs) key = if f x == key then Just x else lookupBy f xs key
```

Then you could use it as

```
main = do
    let people = [Person "John" "Doe" 68 30, Person "Jane" "Smith" 63 28]
    print $ lookupBy firstName people "Jane"
    print $ lookupBy lastName  people "Doe"
    print $ lookupBy age       people 29
    print $ lookupBy height    people 63
```

This would print

```
Just (Person {firstName="Jane", lastName="Smith", height=63, age=28})
Just (Person {firstname="John", lastName="Doe", height=58, age=30})
Nothing
Just (Person {firstName="Jane", lastName="Smith", height=63, age=28})
```

(assuming that it compiles, I have not run this code but it should work).

---

If you want to choose on whether you get a single item or a list of matching items, you could do

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

lookupAllBy :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> b -> [a]
lookupAllBy f xs key = filter (\x -> f x == key) xs

lookupBy :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> b -> Maybe a
lookupBy f xs key = listToMaybe $ lookupAllBy f xs key
```